# Select Different Font Sizes in UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, font-size

Does anyone know how I can set font sizes from an array in a UIPickerView.

```
//Set selectedElement's font to selectedFont
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
ContainerViewController container = (ContainerViewController )[self navigationController].parentViewController;
UITextView selectedText = (UITextView) container.selectedElement;
if(pickerView.tag == 1) {
UIFont selectedFont = [UIFont fontWithName:[availableFonts objectAtIndex:row] size:DEFAULT_FONTSIZE];
[selectedText setFont:selectedFont];
} else {
NSNumber selectedFontSize = [availableFontSizes objectAtIndex:row]

    //Set selectedText's font size to selectectedFontSize


}
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that the code is correspond to the question. As I understood right you need different font for each title in UIPickerView correct?

Comment: for now you check picker tag, I assumed that you have two pickers?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIFont *font1 = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica"];
UIFont *font2 = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold"];
UIFont *font3 = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Helvetica Neue"];

self.availableFonts =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:font1, font2, font3, nil];


//Set selectedElement's font to selectedFont
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
ContainerViewController container = (ContainerViewController )[self navigationController].parentViewController;
UITextView selectedText = (UITextView) container.selectedElement;
if(pickerView.tag == 1) {
UIFont selectedFont = [availableFonts objectAtIndex:row];
[selectedText setFont:selectedFont];
} else {
NSNumber selectedFontSize = [availableFontSizes objectAtIndex:row]

    //Set selectedText's font size to selectectedFontSize


}
}
```